# Database versioning system used by Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, architecture

I know Stack Overflow is in the .NET stack and as a micro [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) they use their own Dapper project. What about database versioning/migrations system? Which system is used by the Stack Overflow team?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nick has blogged about this](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/05/03/stack-overflow-how-we-do-deployment-2016-edition/#database-migrations). Below is a part of it:

> The database migrator we use is a very simple repo we could open source, but honestly, there are dozens out there and the “same migration against n databases” is fairly specific. The others are probably much better and ours is very specific to only our needs. The migrator connects to the Sites database, gets the list of databases to run against, and executes all migrations against every one (running multiple databases in parallel). This is done by looking at the passed-in migrations folder and loading it (once) as well as hashing the contents of every file. Each database has a Migrations table that keeps track of what has already been run. It looks like this (descending order):
>
> [image: screenshot of migrations]

Comment: Well, add me to the list of people it offends.